# Remote Second Level Cache for Hibernate (JPA) by Hazelcast

Tags: hibernate, distributed, hazelcast

Does **Hazelcast** support **Distributed** and **Remote Second Level Cache** for
**Hibernate** when using **JPA**?

I have Client/Server architecture, and my problem is that **Data Access Operations** using JPA are at **the client side**..., when the **cache is a remote server**.

Would please give me a sample of a code to do at the two sides? (at JPA side and Hazelcast side)

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, read the docs http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/3.1/manual/html/ch15.html

Simple example of solution in my project (based on spring):
1. include hazelcast hibernate dependency (for maven)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>${hazelcast.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

(or hazelcast-hibernate3, if needed)

2.enable cache for hibernate in your persistence-context

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" ... > 
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
         <map>
            ...
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_native_client" value="true"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.native_client_address" value="127.0.0.1"/>
         </map>
    </property>
```

3 .Configure cache for some entities.
Profit